# Al intentar comprobar si un email ya está registrado en Flutter, recarga una y otra vez la pantalla

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo estas dos funciones, el `future` llama al `provider` y en teoría comprueba si el email ya está registrado, y después el validador del email donde se incluye esa comprobación.
El problema es que con este código cuando haces click en el botón para ir a la siguiente página, hace un bucle infinito (recargando la página una y otra vez) y no sé cómo resolver que no recargue la página.

Creo que el error está en el `Future` *_isEmailInUse*, concretamente en el último `if` de esa función que hace la validación de todo el formulario.

He aquí el código:

```
         Future<bool?> _isEmailInUse(String value) async {
        final result = await _provider.checkEmail(value);
        bool _inUse = false;
        validating = false;
    
        if (result) {
          _inUse = true;
          message = AppLocalizations.of(context)!.signUpErrorEmailTaken!;
        } else {
          message = "";
        }
        if (_formKey.currentState != null && _formKey.currentState!.validate())
          return _inUse;
      }
    
          String? validateEmail(String? value) {
            if (value != null && value != "") {
              Pattern pattern =
                  r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
              RegExp regex = new RegExp(pattern as String);
              if (!regex.hasMatch(value))
                return AppLocalizations.of(context)!.signUpErrorEmailFormat;
              else {
                if (validating) {
                  _isEmailInUse(value);
                  validating = false;
                  message = " ";
                } else {
                  validating = true;
                }
                if (message.isEmpty) {
                  var passMessage = _validatePassword(_passwordController.value.text);
                  var passRepeatMessage = _validatePasswordConfirm(_repeatPasswordController.value.text);
                  if (passMessage == null && passRepeatMessage == null)
                    _nextPage();
                  return null;
                }
                return message;
              }
            } else {
              return AppLocalizations.of(context)!.signUpErrorEmailEmpty;
            }
          }
  _nextPage() {
    String phone = _phoneController.value.text;

    if (phone.contains(".") ||
        phone.contains(",") ||
        phone.contains("-") ||
        phone.contains(" ")) {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return SimpleInfoDialog(
              alertTitle: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.info,
              alertText: AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                  .alertSignupPhoneNumberFormatText,
            );
          });
      return null;
    }

    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      authModel.setEmail(_emailController.value.text);
      authModel.setPassword(_passwordController.value.text);
      authModel.setPhone(_phoneController.value.text);
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/signup/contact/details",
          arguments: {'authModel': authModel});
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro de lo que está haciendo el bucle infinito, pero podría que su funcion _isEmailInUse puede delvolver un valor null. Este necessita terminar delvolviendo con boolean. Ahora tiene un delaracion 'if, then return'. Necessita devolver _inUse si es true o false.

```
Future<bool?> _isEmailInUse(String value) async {
    final result = await _provider.checkEmail(value);
    bool _inUse = false;
    validating = false;

    if (result) {
      _inUse = true;
      message = AppLocalizations.of(context)!.signUpErrorEmailTaken!;
    } else {
      message = "";
    }
    if (_formKey.currentState != null && _formKey.currentState!.validate()){...}
    return _inUse;
  }
```